# How to split/slice a polygon without subdivide?

Tags: mesh

So I'm relatively new to Blender AND human modelling and was working on this low poly CG character. This torso was built from a cylinder primitive and now I want to split/slice at the very bottom face in two (then I can cut half of it and mirror, extrude the leg or whatever).

The face can't be subdivided and I just want to slice the face in two along the line (shown in the picture as a cyan line) connecting the center vertices.

[image: Cyan line is the slicing guide]

This is Blender 2.66. What do I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use the knife tool. Press <kbd>K</kbd> and then click where you want to make cuts. Press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to confirm:

[image]

Or you could use the join tool. Select the vertices you want to connect with an edge and press <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks! Knife tool was what I needed! And the illustrations helped too!

Comment: What is the difference between using J and pressing F to join vertices?

Comment: @Neil `J` cuts the face(s) between the selected vertices with an edge, `F` just creates an edge. In the above example, `J` results in two faces where there used to be one. `F` would not cut the face, resulting in the same number of faces (but with a floating edge between to verts).

Comment: 'space bar' to execute cutting!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the `J` shortcut - very useful!

Answer (score 4):

Select both vertices and connect them.

- Mesh -> Vertices -> Connect `(menu)`
- JKey `(shortcut)`

While the knife can be used for this purpose too, for quick cuts this is faster.

This also works...

- Between many selected vertex pairs (you can connect multiple faces at once).
- Between 2 vertices - to connect vertices across multiple faces.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use the [Vertex Connect tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/vertex_connect.html).

To do so:

1. Select the two vertices.
2. Press the `J` key or search for the "Vertex Connect" tool.

[image]

[image]

[image]