# How do I split a face in half?

Tags: faces

I want to split this top face into two separate (horizontal) faces:

[image]

I see that you can do [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14989/how-to-split-slice-a-polygon-without-subdivide) with the knife tool, but I don't know how to position the cut so that it's exactly in the centre.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While looking around I found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35244/split-an-edge-in-two) that talks about splitting an edge with Subdivide and thought I'd try it with two opposite edges of a face selected. Turns out it works!

First, click on Edge select:

[image]

Then, select the top and bottom edges, since we want to split the face horizontally. If you want to split the face vertically, select the left and right edges instead.

[image]

Right click somewhere in the scene (don't think it matters where) and select Subdivide from the menu:

[image]

Ta-da! It's split perfectly in two.

[image]

Now you can select each face:

[image]

I'd be interested if anyone has a better way of doing this, as it seems like a very common task.

Comment: This is likely the best way to accomplish this task for a single face. If you want to cut the entire object in half, the Bisect tool is probably your best bet.